How does the Stern-Gerlach example really works?
I looked at a huge amount of information about the spins of particles, and understood only part of the information. I can't "combine" this information in any way.
As I understood it, firstly, spin is a property of particles, as if they rotate, but do not rotate, and they have the properties of a magnet. If so, then fine, then that's not what I'm interested in.
Secondly, particles with spin 1/2, like an electron, must rotate twice to return to their standard state. But particles with spin 1, for example, not. I don't understand why I need this information in all this pile of information. I also realized that the particles rotate discretely, but I didn't really understand how this information is used here.
I was trying to understand the Stern-Gerlach example. The electrons here can only have an "up" or "down" state. How does this even relate to my previous assumptions? Why exactly "up" and "down"? What if there was a particle with spin 1, for example? I'm sorry if I'm forgetting something.

There is a lot more background information that you need to research. The direction of spin polarization is arbitrary. When talking about a spin-$\frac 12$ particle having a spin "up" or "down", we are referring to a 2D vector space where "up" or "down" correspond to one set of basis vectors.

"How does this even relate to my previous assumptions?" "they have the properties of a magnet." "I also realised that the particles rotate discretely," no.

Is this all wrong, naturallyInconsistent?

Not sure why the down and close votes. The OP is confused about spin. This is a common problem. An explanation would be helpful.

Re Stern-Gerlach: In general the spin (angular momentum) of a particle will be in a superposition of different directions, In the SG experiment we select a direction by applying an external magnetic field and this causes the spin to align with the field. So when we talk about spin up and spin down this specifically refers to the direction relative to the external magnetic field.

Thanks, it's clearer now, John Rennie! But please, tell me, how is this related to the fact that the electron needs to rotate 720 degrees to return to some kind of "original" state, or is this not what we are talking about here at all? How exactly does spin 1/2 relate to this experiment? What if the electron had spin 1? Can you frame this as an answer rather than a comment so that I can mark it as correct?

"How exactly does spin 1/2 relate to this experiment?" This is why I really don't like treatments that are very handwavy. A very complete and proper treatment of quantum theory would discuss angular momentum, both what the classical theory predicts, and what quantum theory predicts for what we expect of integer (orbital) angular momentum. If the integer $\ell\in\mathbb Z^+_0$ is the orbital angular momentum of the atom flying in the SG device, then quantum theory predicts that there would be $2\ell+1$ smeared lines for the various states. But SG sees two lines, forcing us to consider spin 1/2
